# SSRS 2008 R2 Create/Modify Role

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am running an instance of Reporting Services 2008 R2 and would like to customize the Browser role.  By default, that role is allowed to view folders, reports and subscribe to reports.  I want to remove the ability of users in the Browser role to subscribe to reports.

Please let me know if this role modification is possible.  If not, is there a way to create a new role that can only view folders and reports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this easily, but the path to this feature is a little unusual. To change the security like this you need to use SQL Server Management Studio to connect to SSRS:
Server type: Reporting Services
Server name: http://servername/reportserver

Once connected you can expand the Security folder and then the Roles folder to display your roles. Double click on "Browser" to get a properties window that should be straight forward. The task you want to deselect is "Manage individual subscriptions."